# Compile template files/stubs into JS variables with Laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I have a folder `/resources/js/stubs`. In that folder sits a few files, lets say `User.stub`, `Controller.stub` and `Migration.stub`. I would like to use the content of these files in my javascript by doing something like this

```
import Templates from './Templates.js'
console.log(Templates.User)
// The content of User.stub is printed
```

I don't want to use this approach

```
module.exports = name => `
...
`
```

I could also use the backend to load the files into the view but I would prefer not to.

So then that requires preprocessing. Can I do it with Laravel mix somehow? If not what are my options, what do I need to add to my Laravel app?

Comment: You probably want to use raw loader https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/

Answer (score 0):

### partial solution

Thanks to **Diogo Sgrillo** for pointing out this solution in the comment.

Install raw-loader
`yarn add raw-loader --dev`

#### webpack.mix.js

Add this configuration (In my case all the files will be named with a `.stub` extension.):

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.stub$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Also add a separate pipe in `webpack.mix.js` like this:

```
mix.js('src/templates/index.js', 'src/templates.js')
```

It will compile a list of templates in `index.js` file and put them in `templates.js`.

#### src/templates/index.js

```
// Dynamically load all stubs using raw-loader (see webpack.mix.js)
let stubs = require.context('./', true, /\.stub$/i);

// Create a object with the filename as key and content as value
exports.stubs = stubs.keys().reduce((result, key) => {
    return {
        [key.replace(/\.\//,'').replace(/\.stub$/,'')] : stubs(key).default,
        ...result
    }
}, {});

export default { /* dont remove this export default or it will break !?? */}
```

Later it can be used like this:

```
let templates = require('./templates.js')
console.log(templates['User.php'])
```

Please comment or add another answer on how to do this more smooth. What is the difference between `exports/export`? I cant use `import` with this method, only require and it breaks if I try to `export default` (or remove `export default`.